# Is there a good way to monitor temperature/fan levels for 16.04?

Tags: hardware, fan, temperature, monitoring

I've been struggling with this for a while and I cant seem to find a solution that works properly.

Comment: Is there any danger to my laptop using a fresh install of ubuntu?